# Exit Loop when first record found

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, plsql, plsql-package

I have a cursor that might return 2 rows for an id . I want to loop through the cursor and exit when the first row for each id is found .

```
Cursor find_c is 
Select t1.year,t1.sum(charges) charge
  from table t1
  join table t2 on t1.id=t2.id and t1.charge_id=t2.charge_id
where t1.id='3456'
group by t1.year
order by 2 desc;
```

Data :

```
Year Charge
2021  12
2020  56
```

Procedure

```
Begin 
For lc in find_c loop 
   IF lc.charge > 0 then 
      lv_year = lc.year
   END IF 
END LOOP
End;
```

The loop should return only the first row i.e) lv_year='2021'.
Adding rownum=1 in the cursor will get me the latest row , but i am looking for something in the for loop to exit when the first year is found for an id

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  You say initially "loop through the cursor and exit when the first row is found" but later say "exit when the first year is found for an id". Those are not the same. Further there is no ID in your sample data. So do you want the **first row** or the **first row for each id**. Please clarify by updating the question.

Comment: @Belayer : Edited the question . Looking to get first row for each id , without use of rownum and fetch next 1 rows only in cursor.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify Oracle database version you use.

If it is 11g, then `fetch` clause won't work (as it didn't exist yet):

```
SQL> select * from dept
  2  fetch next 1 rows only;
fetch next 1 rows only
      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Another answer suggested not to use a cursor nor a loop at all - that perfectly makes sense, but then you have to write some more code to avoid `TOO_MANY_ROWS` (as you can't fit two rows into  scalar variables) and, possibly, `NO_DATA_FOUND`. With a cursor, you don't have to worry about that as Oracle handles it for you.

Therefore, you could do what you described - run only one loop iteration. But, using a loop at all? Do just `open - fetch - close`. It means that your code might look like this (based on Scott's sample schema as I don't have your tables).

Query that "simulates" yours fetches sums of salaries per departments. I'm interested in the highest salary.

```
SQL> select d.dname, sum(e.sal) sumsal
  2  from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  3  group by d.dname
  4  order by sumsal desc;

DNAME              SUMSAL
-------------- ----------
RESEARCH            10875        --> that's what I want
SALES                9400
ACCOUNTING           8750
```

The procedure:

```
SQL> declare
  2    cursor find_c is
  3      select d.dname, sum(e.sal) sumsal
  4      from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  5      group by d.dname
  6      order by sumsal desc;
  7    cur_r find_c%rowtype;
  8    lv_dname dept.dname%type;
  9  begin
 10    open find_c;
 11    fetch find_c into cur_r;
 12
 13    if cur_r.sumsal > 0 then
 14       lv_dname := cur_r.dname;
 15    end if;
 16
 17    dbms_output.put_line('Picked DNAME = ' || lv_dname ||
 18      '. Now, do something here, execute some more code');
 19
 20    -- some code goes here
 21    dbms_output.put_line('First iteration is over; that''s the end');
 22    close find_c;
 23  end;
 24  /
Picked DNAME = RESEARCH. Now, do something here, execute some more code    --> good, RESEARCH is here
First iteration is over; that's the end

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Just to show that without cursor you might get some problems:

TOO_MANY_ROWS:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_dname  dept.dname%type;
  3    l_sumsal number;
  4  begin
  5    select d.dname, sum(e.sal) sumsal
  6      into l_dname, l_sumsal
  7      from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  8      group by d.dname
  9      order by sumsal desc;
 10    dbms_output.put_line('Query executed');
 11  end;
 12  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

NO_DATA_FOUND:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_dname  dept.dname%type;
  3    l_sumsal number;
  4  begin
  5    select d.dname, sum(e.sal) sumsal
  6      into l_dname, l_sumsal
  7      from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  8      where 1 = 2                    --> will cause NO_DATA_FOUND
  9      group by d.dname
 10      order by sumsal desc;
 11    dbms_output.put_line('Query executed');
 12  end;
 13  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 5


SQL>
```

Of course, you *can* fix that (e.g. using exception handler section), but - why bother?

---

[EDIT, based on your comment]

If cursor returns more than a single row for each ID and you want to skip the rest, one option to do that is to use `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to "sort" rows and then fetch only the first one for each ID. In my example based on Scott's tables, that would looks like this:

```
cursor find_c is
  select dname, sumsal
  from (select d.dname, sum(e.sal) sumsal,
          row_number() over (partition by d.dname order by sum(e.sal) desc) rn
        from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
        group by d.dname
       )
  where rn = 1;
```

Adjust it to your data model.

Comment: -Thank you . My cursor will fetch 2 rows for every id that passes through the loop . But i want the loop to fetch the first row of an id and then move to the next id.

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more info at the bottom of the answer. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is one record, then cursor is an overhead. I suggest variables. As the other answer raised a concern on the exceptions, which is a valid scenario too. You can handle the no data found exception as the multiple rows is already handled in my query with fetch first row only.

```
Declare
Var1 <type> :=<initial value>;
Var2 <type> :=<initial value>;

Begin

Select x,y into var1,var2 from <table>
Order by x,y
Fetch first row only;

Exception when no_data_found
Var1 := <some value>;
Var2 := <some value>;
End;
```

Comment: Just a minor note, `FETCH` will work from Oracle 12 (Which everybody should already have as older Oracle DB version support ends soon).

Answer (score 0):

Does not make much sense then to use a cursor for loop for one row, but this should work

```
Cursor find_c is 
Select t1.year,t1.sum(charges) charge
  from table t1
  join table t2 on t1.id=t2.id and t1.charge_id=t2.charge_id
where t1.id='3456'
group by t1.year
order by 2 desc
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Thank you , but i do not want to limit the rows in my cursor .